# Uninitialized constant User::ChatRoom

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I get this error

> NameError (uninitialized constant User::ChatRoom):
> app/controllers/users_controller.rb:20:in `create'

Here is my user.rb file

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :email, type: String
  has_many :chat_room, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Here is my chat_room.rb file

```
class ChatRoom
  include Mongoid::Document
  # Attributes
  field :tittle, type: String
  field :is_private, type: Boolean, default: false
  # Relations

  belongs_to :user
  # Validations and Scope
  scope :public_rooms, -> { where(is_private: false) }
end
```

users_controller.rb file

```
def create
    user = User.new(user_params)

    if user.save
      render json: { status: :created}
    else
      render json: user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

Comment: Where are you actually referencing `ChatRoom`?

Comment: The name of the files should be user.rb, chat_room.rb .

Comment: @user1934428 I am trying to reference chatroom with users

Comment: @Ewerton the file names are user.rb and chat_room.rb in the code

Comment: i think there is some problem with associations because when i remove   `has_many :chat_room, dependent: :destroy`  code works properly

Comment: It should actually be `has_many :chatrooms, dependent: :destroy`  ... it's plural.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn nope still getting the same error

Comment: And I mistyped... `has_many :chat_rooms, dependent: :destroy` (forgot the underscore)

Answer (score 0):

In your class User, change :

> has_many :chat_room, dependent: :destroy

by :

> has_many :chat_rooms, dependent: :destroy

After `has_many`, it should be the plurial class name. And after `belongs_to`, it should be singular class name.